# owl carousel 2 next items

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

It is available in owl carousel 2, if click next button give additional page images? Because the default is only one next item slide.

An example of how it works:

```
[1,2,3] -> (next click) -> [2,3,4]
```

I want

```
[1,2,3] -> (next click) -> [4,5,6]
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this tree items [1,2,3] in one item

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        [1,2,3]
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        [4,5,6]
    </div> 
</div>
```

and add in your JS the number of the items in this case

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    items:1 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the option [slideBy](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)?

`slideBy: 3` (or `"page"`)